# unity 5, how to open saved scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

when I start a new unity 5 2D game. By default, it has scene, game and asset Store tabs. I saved the scene and named it to movementStaging, then closed the scene tab. Now i cannot open it again. I right click on it, and choose open. nothing happens. how can I get the scene tab back?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on another tab ->Add tab -> Scene. Then double clicking on the saved scen should open it in the scene tab. Also restarting unity helps most of the times. You can also try Window -> Layouts -> Default

Comment: thank you.  I didnt know i have to open a new scene tab then double click on the saved scene.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to reset the Window-Layout settings to default. [image: Reset the window layout to default]

Comment: Already covered that in my answer, but the picture is helpful

Comment: Hey Uri, you are totally right, i somehow missed the last sentence.